# If ε or error rate is normally distributed $N(0, σ^2 )$, why is y also $Y ∼ N(µ, σ^2 )$?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, linear-model

*I have the following notes which describe a basic height model:*

If Y has some distribution with mean µ and variance $σ^2$:

E(Y) = µ, Var(Y) = $σ^2$

then this can be written:

Y = µ + ε

i.e.

Data = Fixed parameter + Random variable

**Note that ε = Y − µ and that E(ε) = 0, Var(ε) = $σ^2$, i.e. if ε ∼ N(0,$σ^2$)
then Y ∼ N(µ, $σ^2$)**

*I am trying to understand what this bolded line means and how they made the point ***if ε ∼ N(0, $σ^2$) then Y ∼ N(µ, $σ^2$).***
I don't have any prior experience in topics such as distributions so please do explain in simple language as much as possible.*

Comment: A term of art to get you started is "linearity of expectation."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Short answer

> **Note that ε = Y − µ and that E(ε) = 0, Var(ε) = $σ^2$, i.e. if ε ∼ N(0,$σ^2$)
> then Y ∼ N(µ, $σ^2$)**

If  ε = Y − µ then Y = µ + ε

For a normal distribution if  ε ∼ N(0,$σ^2$) then  ε+ µ ∼ N(µ, $σ^2$)

See also https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Operations_on_a_single_normal_variable

#### Long answer  (Y = µ + ε is not general and special to the normal distribution)

Models are often describing the parameters of distributions of outcomes, like the mean ($\mu$) and the variance ($\sigma^2$). Given some input, e.g. of independent variables, you will expect the outcome to be some sort of distribution.

For instance if you are measuring radiation with a Geiger-Müller counter then you expect for some given input, like radiation strength, duration of measurement, distance to source, the number of counts to be Poisson distributed. $$\text{counts} \vert X \sim Poisson (\lambda) \quad \quad \lambda = f(X) =  \text{some function of input}$$ where this $\text{counts} \vert X$ with the vertical bar means that we describe the distribution of the $\text{counts}$ conditional on the parameters/inputs $X$.

In the case of a Gaussian distribution you can describe the equation in two ways. Say you have a variable $Y$ which will have some mean $\mu(X)$ and standard deviation $\sigma(X)$ depending on the parameters $X$ the

$$Y \sim N\left( \mu(X), \sigma(X) \right)$$

or alternatively

$$Y = \mu(X) + \epsilon \quad\quad \text{with } \epsilon \sim N\left( 0, \sigma(X) \right)$$

The reason that you have this alternative description for Gaussian noise is not just because it happens to be that you can shift a Gaussian distributed variable like $$ \text{if $X \sim N(a, b)$ then $X+c \sim N(a+c, b)$}$$ (see also [scale-location family](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location%E2%80%93scale_family))

Underlying is a more profound principle. Namely, the Gaussian distribution is a description of 'additive noise'. When you consider randomness in some experiment/measurement to be due to little deviations that are *added* to some original value (for instance the mean) then you approach a distribution that is the Gaussian distribution (see the [central limit theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem)).

In many cases an experimenter/scientists has this situation of noise, consisting of many little amounts of different sources of noise, as being *added* to some original signal/value. So they describe the mean $\mu$ plus some error term $\epsilon$.

However, as in the case of the Poisson noise, there are also many cases where you do not have this type of error that can be described as noise that is added to the mean value. The description of this error/noise term $\epsilon$ that is *added* to the mean value is specific to these cases in which the noise is described as Gaussian noise or white noise.

---

TL;DR

- The use of the equation of the type $$Y \sim N\left( \mu(X), \sigma(X) \right)$$ is more general (and will also work for other distributions such as the Poisson distribution).
- The use of the equation of the type
  $$Y = \mu(X) + \epsilon \quad\quad \text{with } \epsilon \sim N\left( 0, \sigma(X) \right)$$ is more specific to the normal distribution and it's associated type of noise which is added to the original $\mu$

Answer (score 3):

Look at this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Operations_on_a_single_normal_variable), specifically the first bullet point.

Informally, $Y$ is a normal random variable ($\epsilon$), shifted by a number $\mu$. If you can visualize a normal curve centered at zero, what would it look like if you shifted it by a number $\mu$?